# Issue with font change in CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, bigcartel

I've recently changed the font in my store hosted on BigCartel with the @font-face feature. Unfortunately there are some characters that still remain with the font from BigCartel. I've added in my CSS these lines:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: GothamBlack;
        src: url(https://github.com/JDRF/design-
system/blob/master/dist/fonts/gotham/black/gotham-black-webfont.woff2); 
    }
    body {
        font-family: GothamBlack, sans-serif;
    }
```

A friend told me to change the  part in the layout tab, but that didn't helped me to fix the issue. Any clue on how can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the font GothamBlack contains all the glyphs that the website is trying to display?

Comment: @MrLister yup. The text that is displayed with the old font is 'quick view' and '25.00€', so I presume that those glyphs are contained in the .woff2 file